# Align images horizontally CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to align my three images horizontally instead of vertically what is the easiest way to achieve this? [example](http://jsfiddle.net/KarinaMcG/tDfCR/)

```
<div id="christmas_promotion_boxes">
            <div id="christmas_promo_1">
                <img src="http://lilliemcferrin.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/vivid_flowers-wide.jpg" width="200" height="100">
            </div>
            <div id="christmas_promo_2">
            <img src="http://lilliemcferrin.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/vivid_flowers-wide.jpg" width="200" height="100">
            </div>
            <div id="christmas_promo_3">
                <img src="http://lilliemcferrin.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/vivid_flowers-wide.jpg" width="200" height="100">
            </div>
        </div>

#christmas_promotion_boxes {width:1000px; margin:0 auto 0 auto; text-align:center;}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Display the divs as `inline-block` like so :

```
#christmas_promotion_boxes div {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tDfCR/4/)**

Answer (score 2):

You need the div's containing the images to be floated.

Add this section of code into your css:

```
#christmas_promotion_boxes > *{
    float:left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tDfCR/5/

Comment: Your are floating everything to the left like that not just the divs.

Comment: No, this is selecting just the direct descendants (which in this case is only the divs)

Comment: Oups my bad, missed the >

Comment: No worries! I chose this method so if he puts any more divs inside of the containing divs, they won't get floated.

Answer (score 2):

When I have inline elements I always put them in a ul and display the li's inline. This way you don't have to worry about floating anything and it is much more scalable.

```
<ul>
  <li id="christmas_promo_1"><img src="http://lilliemcferrin.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/vivid_flowers-wide.jpg" width="200" height="100"></li>
  <li id="christmas_promo_2"><img src="http://lilliemcferrin.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/vivid_flowers-wide.jpg" width="200" height="100"></li>
  <li id="christmas_promo_3><img src="http://lilliemcferrin.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/vivid_flowers-wide.jpg" width="200" height="100"></li>
</ul>

ul{
 width:5em
}

li{
 display:inline;
 list-style-type:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Slightly different from @zazvorniki accepted answer:

```
<div class="christmas_promotion_boxes">
    <img src="http://lilliemcferrin.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/vivid_flowers-wide.jpg" width="200" height="100"/>
    <img src="http://lilliemcferrin.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/vivid_flowers-wide.jpg" width="200" height="100"/>
    <img src="http://lilliemcferrin.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/vivid_flowers-wide.jpg" width="200" height="100"/>
</div>

.christmas_promotion_boxes {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tDfCR/114/

Make sure the `width` is larger the sum all of width of all the images.

Answer (score 0):

add this

```
#christmas_promotion_boxes div{
float: left;
```

}