# horizontal align images html

Tags: html, css, wordpress, css-float

First off, i'm not really a good coder. I'm an IT but more of an infra guy but i do understand concepts about coding and maybe a bit of a good grasp about it. I am working with my website and it's under construction using wordpress. In my homepage, i plan to do it simple as it is and decided to use the page builder and use text or HTML (or any language) to maximize it. I hope some one can help me. I would really appreciate it.

Here it is:
[homepage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wf1Av.png)

Those images have onmouseover style and was able to do it.. the thing is i can't arrange it horizontally. :( and unable include arrow so they can move left or right to see each images :(.

I know i can also do the same on the icon part the moment someone help me about the concept i wanted.

Comment: You also aren't very good at search: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19683184/align-images-horizontally-css One of far too many other duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is pretty ambiguous as to the specific context of the solution.

However, in general the reason why things don't align horizontally when rendered on screen in a browser, is that most elements (including the popular `<div>`) have a default styling of `display: block;` which makes it take up the full width of its parent item if the parent itself has the same styling (cascading of this is a different discussion).

The general solution to this is to define the widths of the elements. And they will be placed on the same line to the extent that the widths of the elements allow for more than one to appear on the same line.

One way to solve this is to have elements widths defined in some way. This could be by applying a class with a `width: 25%;` for example. This would allow for 4 elements with the same width to fit on the line.

Alternately you can also set the `display` property value of the elements you want on the same line to `inline-block`. This will make those elements take the width of it's content (unless the content has no width specified). This will cause the elements to flow along the horizontal line like text would (it will re-flow on the resizing of it's parent element), until there are no more contiguous items containing the `inline-block` display property.

Since your description also showed carousel style navigation for these rows of items, it may be that these are not the full solutions you are looking for.

If you are using the Bootstrap framework, there is a [built-in carousel](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel) feature which you could use to contain these horizontally aligned elements on separate "pages" of the carousel. Making this solution fully responsive is another challenge altogether.