# How to align 3 images in an hortizontal row

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have tried different options that I have found in stackoverflow but none of them seems work for my porpouse.
This is what it happend:
[Problem description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uk8Kq.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read
[what this site is about](http://stackoverflow.com/about) and 
"[How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)" 
before asking a question.

Comment: there are many answers available: like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19683184/align-images-horizontally-css

Comment: Include the HTML and CSS code in the question itself, so that we can check it. Sharing a screenshot of the code is of little help. 
Also, create a fiddle to help us see the issue clearly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

check this out

```css
#christmas_promotion_boxes {width:1000px; margin:0 auto 0 auto; text-align:center;}
#christmas_promotion_boxes div
{
display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="christmas_promotion_boxes">
    <div id="christmas_promo_1">
     <img src="http://lilliemcferrin.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/vivid_flowers-wide.jpg" width="200" height="100">
    </div>
    <div id="christmas_promo_2">
    <img src="http://lilliemcferrin.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/vivid_flowers-wide.jpg" width="200" height="100">
    </div>
    <div id="christmas_promo_3">
     <img src="http://lilliemcferrin.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/vivid_flowers-wide.jpg" width="200" height="100">
    </div>
   </div>
```